# Spring Boot App does not work corretly anymore after running on a subpath

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I have an app which runs on the root path on a server but our client wants to now access it from another domain on a subpath.

```
internal url: app.xyz.com
client domain: otherapp-com/maintenance/
```

all request from `otherapp-com/maintenance/` are forwarded by some proxy to `app.xyz.com`

The app uses freemarker and everything looks good on `app.xyz.com`, but on `otherapp-com/maintenance/` the UI is broken because CSS and js files could not be found . In chrome i see the requests go to `otherapp-com/js/...` but they are located on `otherapp-com/maintenance/js/..`

How can I fix this?

In Freemarker templates, I import scripts like this

```
<script src="js/datatables/1.10.19/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Same problem I have with Spring Security Setting for login and logout URLs

Current Config is

```
//HttpSecurity http
       http.authorizeRequests()
                ...
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
```

Login goes also to `otherapp-com/login` not to `otherapp-com/maintenance/login`, same for logout

Comment: I guess here is about absolute and relative paths in your html or thymeleaf patterns. Take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Also if you use Thymeleaf revise documentation about `@{}` expression which should be used for proper link generation

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski i dont use thymeleaf but freemarker